# Converting a list of string values to rows in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'd like to convert a list of literal values into columns using Snowflake. I've googled around and there are a lot of answer stating `FLATTEN()` can achieve it so I've tried that but it doesn't give me exactly what I want

```sql
select value from table(flatten(input => parse_json('["user1","user2"]')))
```

that returns:

| VALUE |
| --- |
| "user1" |
| "user2" |

But I do not want the quotes around the values. I can easily strip them off like so:

```sql
select replace(value, '"', '') 
from (
  select value 
  from table(flatten(input => parse_json('["user1","user2"]')))
)
```

but that doesn't feel like the most elegant way of achieving my aim. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value has VARIANT data type and should be explicitly casted:

```
select value::TEXT
from table(flatten(input => parse_json('["user1","user2"]')))
```